# Polynomials and evenness

Tags: functions, polynomials

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

Let $P$ be a polynomial in ${\mathbb R}[x]$. We assume that $P$ factors in ${\mathbb R}[x]$ as $P=Q_1Q_2$. Then, if $P$ is odd or even, then $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are also even or odd.

I have no idea on how I could prove this, so some hints (or a counter-example, if any) are welcome. The motivation of the question is to prove that if a rational function $f(x)$ is even (resp. odd), only even (resp. odd) partial fractions appear. This would give a method to simplify the computation of coefficients appearing in the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Notice that $P$ is odd implies that $P=XQ(X^2)$ and if $P$ is even then $P=Q(x^2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$
P
=
S 
=
x^{4} + 1
=
(x^{2} + \sqrt{2} x - 1) \cdot (x^{2} - \sqrt{2} x - 1)
$$
for the case of $P$ even, and then $P = x S$ for the case of $P$ odd.

Comment: Good. You can even do it in the integers, by looking at $x^4+4$.

Comment: How could I have missed this example? I just did this factorization today. Twice.

Comment: Good point, @GerryMyerson, thanks.

Comment: @Taladris, don't worry, it happens to most if not all of us.

Comment: You could even look at $P = (x-1)(x+1) = x^2 - 1$ wich is even but none of the two factors is even / odd. Likewise for $x(x-1)(x+1)$ and any factorisation thereof.

Comment: @AlexR, even better/simpler, thanks!